# Regular Expression - Only first character check non-letter characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've started to study on javascript and regexp specially. I am trying to improve myself on generating regular expressions.

What I am trying to do is - I have a name field in my html file (its in a form ofc)

```
...
    <label for="txtName">Your Name*: </label>
    <input id="txtName" type="text" name="txtName" size="30" maxlength="40">
...
```

And in my js file I am trying to check name cannot start with any NON-letter character, only for the first character. 
And whole field cannoth contain any special character other than dash and space.

They cannot start with any non-letter character ;

```
/^[A-Z a-z][A-Z a-z 0-9]*$/
```

They cannot contain any symbol other than dash and space ;

```
/^*[[&-._].*]{1,}$/
```

When I am testing if it works, it doesn't work at all. In which part am I failing ?

Comment: Remove the spaces between 'Z' and 'a', first of all.

Comment: Also, use [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) to build your regular expressions bit by bit which will immediately tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that typo thanks @caleb.breckon ! Thanks for the tip #Chandranshu , testing them right now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 -]*$/`
When you include a space in the character listing (`[]`), it's going to be allowed in the string that's being searched.

`^[A-Za-z]` matches the first character and says that it must be a letter of some sort.
`[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$` will match any remaining characters(if they exist) after the first character and make sure it's alpha numeric, or contains spaces or dashes.

Comment: Then the whole statement will be enough for these 2 conditions, If I understand correctly?

Comment: According to the rules you gave, yes.